# Instruments blocks Background Thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, instruments

**EDIT:**
Today I worked with my code a bit and gave background thread task some advantages over the main thread task.  Essentially one thread is working with the even numbered items in an array and the other is working with the odd numbers.  I gave the background thread the even number half, which will be either equal to or one less than the odd half.  Also, I moved the `while(!collisionDone)` to a bit later in the code, as far back as I can to keep it thread safe.  I put an `NSLog` in there to detect if the condition is ever false when it reaches that point, and it has not fired once.  Furthermore, the instruments build now runs fine.  That means the problem is stalling the main thread with the while loop.  So that means my question now is:

How should I stall the main thread to wait until the background thread completes a task?  Perhaps demonstrate how one uses `NSLock` to achieve that functionality?

Today I added multithreading in an attempt to reduce lag in my game.  I am using an NSTimer to call my time loop function like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(time:) userInfo: nil repeats: true];
```

Then, in that function, I have:

```
//run collision using multithreading
    collisionDone = false;
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(collideBackground:) withObject:objectToSend];
    [self collideMain:objectToSend];
    while (!collisionDone) {
        //notdone
    }
```

The idea is that I am running one set of collision checks on one thread and another set in another thread.  The empty while loop is to ensure the background thread has completed before carrying on in the function.  After this bit, the code goes on to update the view.

This all runs fine, normally, but when I went to Instruments to check on my FPS, I found that the game freezes, it appears that it is freezing somewhere in the first run of the time loop.  The app ran fine in Instruments before the multithreading, which essentially worked the same, except simply using `[self collideBackground:objectToSend]` rather than sending it to another thread.  It would appear that the background thread is not completing or not being run at all, so collisionDone will always be false, and therefore the app will wait in that endless loop until I kill it.

Also, I have tried replacing that line with `[self collideBackground:arrayToSend];`, and it starts working again.  Another thing I tried is putting `NSLog(@"called");` at the very start of `viewWillAppear:` and it seems to run exactly one more frame!?!?!?

I would like any ideas as to why exactly this is happening and how to fix it.  I doubt it is unrelated to the multithreading as doing everything on a single thread fixes it.

Comment: you might want to join your threads instead of doing a busy wait, check  [this answer out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614780/how-to-join-threads-in-objective-c-without-using-delegates-callback) probably wont fix your problem, but its a better way of going about threading

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm not exactly sure how I am supposed to use NSLock or any of its subclasses to have the main thread wait for a background thread to complete.  I understand that the while loop isn't the most efficient way of waiting.  Anyway, as of the latest edit to my code, the condition will only be false when it gets to the while loop in rare cases (see my edit).

Comment: use the grand central dispatch method in that answer, much simpler to implement/understand.

Comment: grand dispatch center approach doesn't work.  When placing NSLogs, I find that it excecutes the main thread calculations, then waits until the dispatch_group_wait(myGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); line before doing the background calculations.  NSThread and performSelectorInBackground are the only ways I have detected actual multithreading action.

Comment: maybe try use `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)` in the async call, the answer i linked didnt specify that so maybe it was using the main thread by default or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution after talking to my programmer friend about it at school:

```
//threadLock is an NSLock declared in the .h
-(void)timeLoop {
     [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(collideBackground) withObject:nil];
     [self collideMainAtStartingPoint:0];

     [threadLock lock];
     [threadLock unlock];

     //update the view hierarchy and stuff like that
}
-(void)collideBack {
     [threadLock lock];
     [self collideMainAtStartingPoint:2];
     [threadLock unlock];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is related to multithreading, and your poll on the main thread. You should put a callback into your background thread instead. And not blocking the main thread.

```
// is not good at all
collisionDone = false;
/*  etc... that will make collision to true */
 while (!collisionDone) {
    }
```

make instead

```
  [self computeSomethingOnBagroundWhithData: nil onCompletion:^{
    // callBack stuff
}]
```

**Edit:**

while (!collisionDone)

is always true because when you are creating another thread, the instruction is stuck in "while" statement, and is not reevaluating each time "collisionDone" as you would expect, but evaluate it inside the while scope. By the way, there could be some optimizer stuff, and "collisionDone" could only be evaluated in local scope (but here I'm only guessing, since it's compiler dependent). You should reenter the method in order to make it work, or join the thread when you are done. Since you don't want complex code for this kind of stuff, block are exactly what you want. libDispatch are perfect for this.

So you can try "self.collisionDone" in order to try to get the genuine pointer. But there's lot of chance that won't change anything.

Or you can do your stuff in background and when you are done, send a signal / callback to your client code. You don't need to make polling like you did. This is really bad design (really trust me ;) )

Comment: I need to wait until both the main thread function and the background thread function are complete before continuing.  Also, there is a lot of stuff after that point in the function, and most of it involves rearranging the view, so it must be done on the main thread.

Comment: I am going to need one of the threads to wait; I must make sure both threads have completed their processing before continuing.  I have considered using performSelectorOnMainThread:, but then I cannot be certain that the main thread processing is complete.

Answer (score 0):

It has been unclear what the best approach to solving this problem or what the actual cause of the problem (yes it is that `while(!collisionDone)` loop, but why?), but none of the proposed alternatives can do the job properly.  Although other options have been suggested, NSThread and performSelectorInBackground: have been the only ways I have detected the functionality I am looking for.  Furthermore, after testing with the multithreading part turned off, I realized that the iPhone 4s has a much, much better processor than the iPhone 4, and I can run the game at 60 FPS on the iPhone 4s and newer without multithreading (the iPhone 4 can only handle 30 FPS).  Lastly, I intended for my multithreading to utilize the dual-core processor of the iPhone 4s, so half of the collision would be done in one core while the other core does the other half.  I am not sure this is actually happening and I have no idea how to detect this.

My conclusion: Remove this attempt at multithreading from the app completely.  It is unnecessary and the benefits are dubious.

@Fonix: The question you linked to shows exactly what I am trying to do, however, none of the solutions they presented seem to be working.