# Can I allocate a task to a specific core in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, multithreading

Just a quick question. Say I have an application that does some heavy calculation. Is it possible to run to UI code on one core, and then do all the calculations on the other core?
If yes, how do you do this?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

To clarify, I don't mean running on different threds, but on another core. The calculations should get a whole core for itself.

Comment: You'd need to use [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 3):

Just use Grand Central Dispatch. All UI updates go to the main queue, all heavy background processing to a background queue. The usual code pattern looks like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    [self doHeavyCalculation];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateUI];
    });
});
```

Allocating a task to a specific core is something that should be left to the system, you’re running on a multitasking OS and there are many things that your app doesn’t know about. If there’s (mostly) just you app running and you dispatch something on a background queue, the background task gets its own core.

Comment: I think he imagines something like `if (number_of_cores() > 1) { dispatch_to_core( NON_UI_CORE_ID, ^{…}); }`, but that doesn’t work on a multitasking system.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: yes, the UI is always running on the main thread, any calculations you can do on main or a background thread [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614780/how-to-join-threads-in-objective-c-without-using-delegates-callback) might be useful.